# Issue with grid and Blender Unit (Screenshot attached)

Tags: units

I hope all is well. I've been having an issue with Grids and the Blender Unit during my 3D designs.

For context, I want to set the Blender Unit (length) to be 1:1 with millimeters. I'm expecting that to mean that every subdivision of the grids should equal 1 mm. But, as you can see from the screenshot, it still equals 1000 mm or 1 meter.

Does anyone happen to know what I'm doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the *unit scale* to `.001`. The drop down settings only affect what prefix is used to display the units, not the actual scaling.

[image]